# How do you view the request details including headers, host that Kong is Making?

Tags: kong

I am using kong as an API gateway.

I am struggling to debug the requests that kong is making to upstreams.

I have tried using the `syslog` plugin, but that only logs the request kong receives and the response it sends back to the client.
I am looking to debug the request kong sends to the upstream and the response it receives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enabled a logging plugin, ensure you check in that location.

In my case with `syslog` enabled I viewed `/var/log/syslog` and found:

```
  Apr 30 12:49:34 db kong[7467]: {"latencies":{"request":3100,"kong":1148,"proxy":1952},
  "service": ...
```

It stores alot of information about the request and response but no body info.

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug the requests that sent by Kong, you could watch your Kong error log, it is usually located at */usr/local/kong/logs/error.log* for unix OS.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a solution for kubernetes ingress.
I enabled this [file plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/file-log/) and redirected the output to `/dev/stdout` instead of file. It stared showing the header information in kong logs.

- Global Plugin

```yaml
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongClusterPlugin
metadata:
  name: global-file-log
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong

config:
  path: /dev/stdout
  reopen: false
plugin: file-log
```

Add this plugin to your ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: microservice-ingress
  namespace: something
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "kong"
    konghq.com/plugins: global-file-log
spec:
  rules:
.
.
```

Life became good again after this of-course.